# looping through variable using os.path.join

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to process XML files one-by-one in the directory. Basically reading the values and then populate CSV file. I am having trouble parsing each XML one by one. Issue with my code is csvWriter.writerow only write the values from the last XML file in the directory. Even I have a loop for all items in root of ElementTree.parse(path). I want it to write each line for each XML file in the directory.

```
from lxml import etree as ElementTree
import csv
import os
import errno
import shutil


def writeData(item):
    csvFile = open('D:\\metadata.csv', 'w', newline='')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter='|',
                           lineterminator='\n')
    csvWriter.writerow([
        'type',
        'object',
        'title',
        'subject',
        'domain',
        'name',
        '_name',
        'version_label',
        'creator_name',
        'creation_date',
        'modifier',
        'modify_date',
        'content_type',
        'chronicle_id',
        'antecedent_id',
        'activity_date',
        'search_from_date',
        'number',
        'service_code',
        'initial_inspection_date',
        'search_to_date',
        'File Name',
        'Location',
        ])
    csvWriter.writerow([
        root[0][0].text,
        root[0][1].text,
        root[0][2].text,
        root[0][3].text,
        root[0][4].text,
        root[0][5].text,
        root[0][6].text,
        root[0][7].text,
        root[0][8].text,
        root[0][9].text,
        root[0][10].text,
        root[0][11].text,
        root[0][12].text,
        root[0][13].text,
        root[0][14].text,
        root[0][15].text,
        root[0][16].text,
        root[0][17].text,
        root[0][18].text,
        root[0][19].text,
        root[0][20].text,
        root[2].text,
        root[1].text,
        ])
    csvFile.close()



for file in os.listdir('D:\\temp\\Export\\test'):
    if file.endswith('.xml'):
        path = os.path.join('D:\\temp\\Export\\test', file)
        tree = ElementTree.parse(path)
        #print(tree)
        root = tree.getroot()
        #print(root)
        for item in root:
            print(item)
            writeData(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only see the data of the last xml file, is that you keep overwriting the data in the final .csv file. Instead of reopening the .csv file for every write iteration, try opening it just once, and passing it to your `writeData` function like this:

```
def writeData(csv_writer, item):
    csv_writer.writerow([
        'type',
        'object',
        'title',
        'subject',
        'domain',
        'name',
        '_name',
        'version_label',
        'creator_name',
        'creation_date',
        'modifier',
        'modify_date',
        'content_type',
        'chronicle_id',
        'antecedent_id',
        'activity_date',
        'search_from_date',
        'number',
        'service_code',
        'initial_inspection_date',
        'search_to_date',
        'File Name',
        'Location',
        ])
    csv_writer.writerow([
        root[0][0].text,
        root[0][1].text,
        root[0][2].text,
        root[0][3].text,
        root[0][4].text,
        root[0][5].text,
        root[0][6].text,
        root[0][7].text,
        root[0][8].text,
        root[0][9].text,
        root[0][10].text,
        root[0][11].text,
        root[0][12].text,
        root[0][13].text,
        root[0][14].text,
        root[0][15].text,
        root[0][16].text,
        root[0][17].text,
        root[0][18].text,
        root[0][19].text,
        root[0][20].text,
        root[2].text,
        root[1].text,
        ])

with open('D:\\metadata.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:

    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|', lineterminator='\n')
    for file in os.listdir('D:\\temp\\Export\\test'):
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            path = os.path.join('D:\\temp\\Export\\test', file)
            tree = ElementTree.parse(path)
            root = tree.getroot()
            writeData(csv_writer, root)
```

Comment: Thanks but ... Getting error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extractMetadata.py", line 70, in <module>
    writeData(csv_writer, item)
  File "extractMetadata.py", line 11, in writeData
    csvWriter.writerow([
NameError: name 'csvWriter' is not defined

Comment: Woops my bad, I renamed `csvWriter` to `csv_writer` last minute and apparently forgot a variable. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks one more modification I did... actually we don't need second loop "for item in root:" its duplicating the data. Do you know to make header row only once?

Comment: Great to hear! As for your remark on the second loop, it just depends on what your XML file looks like. Since there was no example of that in your question, I didn't touch that part of the code.

Comment: Doesn't allow me for some reason.